# What does it means vpf in a XML to create a scenario for SAP B1if?

Tags: xml, xslt, sapb1

I am creating a scenario in B1if, and I have some doubts referred vpf word. For example, the code below is using the command `<xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/@*"/>` to copy some data, but the word vpf What exactly makes reference?

Also, sometimes you use `<Payload Role="R"` and sometimes you use `vpf:Payload[@Role='S']/`, why sometimes is "R" and other times is "S"?

```
<xsl:template match="/bfa:unbranch">
        <Msg xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
                <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/vpf:Header"/>
                <Body>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/*"/>
                        <Payload Role="R" id="{$atom}">
                                <xsl:call-template name="transform"/>
                        </Payload>
                </Body>
        </Msg>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@Role='S']/cfdi:Comprobante/@*" />
```

Comment: `vpf` is an [XML Namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

Answer (score 0):

vpf is a XML namespace used in the mapping

When you use Payload R, you refer to Receiver, This section contains the receiver message.

and Payload S, is the Sender, this section contains, the message that you're sending to the integration

```
<vpf:Msg MessageId="100518083505971270420A140FBBB876" …>
  <vpf:Header>
    <vpf:IPO Id="..."/>
    <vpf:Sender Id="0010000101" ObjId="infile"/>
    <vpf:Receiver Id="0010000102"/>
    <vpf:vBIU Id="sap.Tutor-FileToDB" SId="sap.B1iFW-Test" filter=""/>
    <vpf:Identification Ident="File Name" IdPar=""/>
    <vpf:nsList/>
    <vpf:Variables> ... </vpf:Variables>
    <vpf:VarProperties> ... </vpf:VarProperties>
  </vpf:Header>
  <vpf:Body>
    <vpf:Payload Role="T" Type="xxx">
      Trigger Message
    </vpf:Payload>
    <vpf:Payload Role="S">
      Sender Message
    </vpf:Payload>        
    <vpf:Payload id="atom1">
      Result from step with id=atom1
    </vpf:Payload>  
    …
    <vpf:Payload id="atomn">
      Result from step with id=atomn
    </vpf:Payload>        
    <vpf:Payload Role="R">
      Receiver Message
    </vpf:Payload>
  </vpf:Body>
</vpf:Msg>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that will help me to undestand this way better :)